# Adding custom pages to uninstaller

Tags: installation, nsis, uninstallation

I am creating a custom page in my uninstaller as follows:

```
UninstPage custom mypageCreate
.....
.....
.....
Function mypageCreate
   ;call nsDialogs or InstallOptions functions here
FunctionEnd UninstPage custom mypageCreate
```

But I am getting an error-
Error- resolving create-page function "mypageCreate" in uninstall pages.
Help..

Comment: Oops I guess the newline character dint wrk!!
Hope u all read it right...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it must be prefixed with "un." :

```
UninstPage custom un.mypageCreate
Function un.mypageCreate
...
```